# How to prove an assertion containing pointer operations

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to prove a simple assertion using the WP plugin of frama-c. The C code was generated from a Targetlink lookup table. My aim is to provide enough annotations to the function that I can use the resulting contract to prove properties of a calling program. As a first step I wrote an assertion near the beginning of the function that compares a constant against a value obtained from dereferenced pointers, see the following example.

```
typedef struct MAP_Tab1DS0I2T3_b_tag {
   int Nx;
   const int * x_table;
   const int * z_table;
} MAP_Tab1DS0I2T3_b;

int LARA_GearEnaCndn_X[9] =
{
   -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8
};

int LARA_GearEnaCndn_Z[9] =
{
   1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};


MAP_Tab1DS0I2T3_b Sb218_LARA_GearEnaCndn_CUR_map = {
   9,
   (const int *) &(LARA_GearEnaCndn_X[0]),
   (const int *) &(LARA_GearEnaCndn_Z[0])
};

/*@ requires x == 2; */
int Tab1DS0I2T3_b(const MAP_Tab1DS0I2T3_b * map, int x)
{
   /* SLLocal: Default storage class for local variables | Width: 8 */
   int Aux_U8;
   int Aux_U8_a;
   int Aux_U8_b;
   int Aux_U8_c;

   /* SLLutLocalConst: Default storage class for local variables | Width: 32 */
   const int * x_table /* Scaling may differ through function reuse. */;
   const int * z_table /* Scaling may differ through function reuse. */;

   x_table = map->x_table;
   z_table = map->z_table;

   //@ assert (x < x_table[(int) (map->Nx - 1)]);

   if (x <= *(x_table)) {
      /* Saturation. */
      return z_table[0];
   }
   if (x >= x_table[(int) (map->Nx - 1)]) {
      return z_table[(int) (map->Nx - 1)];
   }

   /* Linear search, start low. */
   x_table++;
   while (x > *(x_table++))    {
      z_table++;
   }
   x_table -= 2 /* 2. */;
   Aux_U8 = *(z_table++);
   Aux_U8_a = *(z_table);

   /* Interpolation. */
   Aux_U8_b = (int) (((int) x) - ((int) x_table[0]));
   Aux_U8_c = (int) (((int) x_table[1]) - ((int) x_table[0]));
   if (Aux_U8 <= Aux_U8_a) {
      /* Positive slope. */
      Aux_U8 += ((int) ((((int) (int) (Aux_U8_a - Aux_U8)) * ((int) Aux_U8_b)) /
       Aux_U8_c));
   }
   else {
      /* Negative slope. */
      Aux_U8 -= ((int) ((((int) (int) (Aux_U8 - Aux_U8_a)) * ((int) Aux_U8_b)) /
       Aux_U8_c));
   }
   return Aux_U8;
}
```

Can someone give me a hint which annotations I need to succeed with the proof?
From a look at the Coq proof obligation I see that there are no axioms for operations like "addr_of_data" or "access" which I need for rewriting the terms. Also the information of the global variables referenced in the assertion are missing.

```
1 subgoals
______________________________________(1/1)
forall x_0 map_0 : Z,
is_sint32 x_0 ->
forall m_0 : array data,
x_0 = 2 ->
forall x_table_0 : Z,
x_table_0 = addr_of_data (access m_0 (addr_shift map_0 1)) ->
2 <
sint32_of_data
  (access m_0
     (addr_shift x_table_0
    (as_sint32 (sint32_of_data (access m_0 (addr_shift map_0 0)) - 1))))
```

BR,
Harald

Answer (score 4):

The **addr_of_data**, **addr_shift** etc exioms are automatically given in the **store_model.v** tab of your coq-ide.

Your example nowhere states that **map** gets **Sb218_LARA_GearEnaCndn_CUR_map**
as the actual parameter. Without that the assertion can be wrong.

Now, I don't know how to make **wp** utilize the explicit values of global initializers as parts of a proof. There are some *global invariants* in ACSL, but **wp** doesn't seem to treat them anyhow. So I'll use an explicit *require* statements for the needed values.

Given the following set of statements in the function header:

```
/*@ requires x == 2; 
    requires map->x_table == Sb218_LARA_GearEnaCndn_CUR_map.x_table;
    requires map->Nx == Sb218_LARA_GearEnaCndn_CUR_map.Nx;
    requires LARA_GearEnaCndn_X[8] == 8;
    requires Sb218_LARA_GearEnaCndn_CUR_map.Nx == 9;
    requires Sb218_LARA_GearEnaCndn_CUR_map.x_table == LARA_GearEnaCndn_X;
    requires Sb218_LARA_GearEnaCndn_CUR_map.z_table == LARA_GearEnaCndn_Z;
*/
```

I was able to prove the needed assertion.

The first one is yours.
The second and the third ones are explicit expansion of `*map=Sb218_LARA_GearEnaCndn_CUR_map`
in order not to mess with address ranges.
The rest reflects the initializer values.

Comment: Regarding the initial values of global variables (including those coming from an explicit initializer) WP uses them if and only if Frama-C's option -lib-entry is not set, and if option -main is set to the function that is being proven (here Tab1DS0I2T3_b). In all other cases, their values might have been changed during another call, and you must supply those invariants yourselves, currently as requires.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. With the initialization of the map variable and the -main option I was able to do the proof.